# Finding first value depending on condition

Tags: sql

I have the following table `ticks`

| datetime | lowest_tick | tick_lower |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-01 00:02:00 | 204406 | 204306 |
| 2022-10-01 00:03:00 | 204395 | 204295 |
| 2022-10-01 00:04:00 | 204487 | 204387 |
| 2022-10-01 00:05:00 | 204200 | 204100 |
| 2022-10-01 00:06:00 | 204220 | 204120 |
| 2022-10-01 00:07:00 | 204120 | 204020 |

What I want to get is to show the first value `tick_lower_position` for `tick_lower` when `tick_lower <= lowest_tick`

So the resulting table should look like this

| datetime | lowest_tick | tick_lower | tick_lower_position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-01 00:02:00 | 204406 | 204306 | 204306 |
| 2022-10-01 00:03:00 | 204395 | 204295 | 204306 |
| 2022-10-01 00:04:00 | 204487 | 204387 | 204306 |
| 2022-10-01 00:05:00 | 204200 | 204100 | 204100 |
| 2022-10-01 00:06:00 | 204220 | 204120 | 204100 |
| 2022-10-01 00:07:00 | 204120 | 204020 | 204100 |

So far, I have tried to apply the lag function but cannot figure out how to use lag function with the desired condition.

Comment: Why the position_tick_lower changes in row 4? What's the partitioning based on?

Comment: Please explain the logic behind the `tick_lower_position` or `position_tick_lower` column, whatever you want to call it. It would be easier to understand perhaps if your sample data were simply values like `1,2,3`

Comment: because the previous value in row 3 is greater than `lowest_tick` in row 4
so `tick_lower_position` must match the condition `tick_lower <=  lowest_tick'

Comment: Exactly how are you determining a previous or next row?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was going to ask. I see that 204287 > 204200, but what makes you display the rows in that order?

Comment: Perhaps you have an ID sequence or date column you're not showing? If so this is needed to explain your desired results.

Comment: I'm really sorry for this poorly made example. I've changed the value in 3rd row so the logic should be correct now

Comment: I also have added DateTime column in case it will help

Comment: Can you please tag the DBMS that you're currently using ...?

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the database you are using so I'll assume it's PostgreSQL. You can do:

```
select y.*, first_value(tick_lower) 
  over(partition by g order by datetime) as tick_lower_position
from (
  select x.*, sum(i) over(order by datetime) as g
  from (
    select t.*, case when lowest_tick <
      lag(tick_lower) over(order by datetime) 
      then 1 else 0 end as i
    from t
  ) x
) y
```

Result:

```
 datetime             lowest_tick  tick_lower  i  g  tick_lower_position 
 -------------------- ------------ ----------- -- -- ------------------- 
 2022-10-01 00:02:00  204406       204306      0  0  204306              
 2022-10-01 00:03:00  204395       204295      0  0  204306              
 2022-10-01 00:04:00  204487       204387      0  0  204306              
 2022-10-01 00:05:00  204200       204100      1  1  204100              
 2022-10-01 00:06:00  204220       204120      0  1  204100              
 2022-10-01 00:07:00  204120       204020      0  1  204100
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OYSHhzsp).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work in the case when tick_lower rises and then drops.
here is an example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yGsfOmxx) .
.for the last row tick_lower_position should be equal to 204306 as it is lesser than 204414

Comment: @IvanRoptanov That seems to be a new logic that is not explained in the question. Please edit the question to explain that extra logic, ideally with an example.